# Rails 3.1: Couldn't find rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, capistrano, ubuntu-10.04, passenger

I try run via Capistrano my app. Also i use:

```
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS 
Phusion Passenger 
PostgreSQL 9 
Nginx 
Rails 3.1.3 
Ruby 1.9.3
```

After i did

```
cap deploy:update
```

It creates folders and etc.

Then i try in **/current** folder

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

And now it shows next:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But its installed! I tried `$ bundle install`, `$ gem update rake` it didn't help. This error appears again and again.

**$ gem list**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.3)
actionpack (3.1.3)
activemodel (3.1.3)
activerecord (3.1.3)
activeresource (3.1.3)
activesupport (3.1.3)
ansi (1.4.1)
arel (2.2.1)
autotest (4.4.6)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.13)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.11)
gravatar_image_tag (1.0.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19)
json (1.6.5)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
passenger (3.0.11)
pg (0.12.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.3)
railties (3.1.3)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.1.12)
sass-rails (3.1.5)
sprockets (2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
sys-uname (0.9.0)
texticle (2.0)
therubyracer (0.9.9)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.2)
will_paginate (3.0.2)
ZenTest (4.6.2)
```

**$gem list rake**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
```

Here is my **config/deploy.rb**

```
set :user, "root"                                                             

set :rails_env, "production"

default_run_options[:pty] = true                                              
set :repository,  "git://github.com/Loremaster/sample_app.git"

set :application, "ror_tutorial"
set :deploy_to, "/vol/www/apps/#{application}"

set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

server "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", :app,
                          :web,
                          :db, :primary => true



# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
end
```

**Capfile**

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'

Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

**UPD:** I fixed error with Rake by adding rake gem in gemfile and then run `bundle install` on my local machine and then upload it on server via Capistrano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed error with Rake by adding `gem rake` in gemfile and then run `bundle install` on my local machine and then upload it on server via Capistrano.

Comment: I do not believe this is the correct way to do it, though it may work. Did my answer below work, because a better way to do it would be to let the capistrano user be the only one who can do rails commands. Also, rake really shouldn't be in the gemfile.

Comment: I don't have such user as 'capistrano' in my system. This is first. And i got error 'Could not find rake' each time i tried to run 'rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load' and this is second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

It needs to run rake within the context of bundler.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. 'Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources'

Comment: Are you running it as the same user you have set up in your deploy.rb file (in this case: root)?

Comment: Yes, i do! I do it via ssh and i'm 'root' user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of root, I believe you have to do it as capistrano. Try this:

```
sudo su capistrano
```

Then input your password, and do

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```